# Logitech G13 changes LCD automatically, can it change the profile automatically, too?

Tags: hardware, star-trek-online

I am currently using a Logitech G13 to play Star Trek Online. Without any action on my part, the G13 seems to be aware of whether I am playing on a surface map or a space map. On surface maps, I get a health bar and a shield bar; in space, it shows a hull bar, plus four separate shield bars - one for each facing.

I use two different control sets (selected with the long, thin buttons under the LCD), each with different keymappings. The device appears to know which environment I'm playing in, because it changes the LCD. Is there a way to make it change the control set to match?

Comment: That would be something Cryptic would need to implement because they are sending the data to the G13 about the different health bars. I don't think there is a way to do this.

Comment: A mod was nice enough to undelete your question. I can't really think of any way to improve your question, but I've given it an upvote since I think it's a good question. As someone who loves customizing their G600 Mouse for every game I can definitely relate to this,  and I know I'd find it useful if I ever played Star Trek Online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The G13 **doesn't** actually know what environment you're in. The LCD content is not generated by the G13.

The game panel is simply outputting a bitmap provided to it by the game. What you are interpreting as the device switching modes is simply the game drawing a dramatically different picture to the G13's screen. The G13 remains unaware that a gameplay change has happened.

Answer (score -2):

*Edited: 2/26/2020 To clarify and add solution suggestions.*

Unfortunately not in the way you would like.

The way Logitech does profile swapping and the way the LCD screen renders certain game elements are entirely unconnected.

The LCD screen interfaces with the currently running game (the executable (.exe) file running) to display information. This is implemented by the developer of the game.

Logitech's software does support an automatic profile switch feature. This is activated in the software by selecting the .exe file that is the program or game you want to trigger the profile switch when it runs. So in the case of Star Trek Online, you'd find its .exe file and add it to the Logitech software and then design the profile you'd like to use while it's active.

However, you cannot switch profiles automatically based on events taking place in the game, only based on a different game running.

What you can do however is set a key to toggle between different profiles, so you could tap a key a few times when you change mission types to activate the desired profile.

Notably, combining the profiles the user manually rotates between and automatic game profiles has led to a lot of undesired automatic switching when I've tried it, so I would reccomend setting two manual profiles (that don't activate automatically) and toggle between them as needed.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, I'm saying the answer is, in all likelihood, no.  Now whether the developer could set that up I don't know, but they haven't done so.

Comment: I owned a G15 for years, when the developer chooses to support it the game outputs data such as health and ammo to the keyboard, mouse, or other hardware.  The devices also have the ability to swap profile based on currently running .exe.  These features are independent of one another, however unlike profile swapping, the custom visuals like health bars are entirely in the hands of the developer.

Comment: Here's an official list of officially supported titles for the LCD, however like most resources about the G series LCD I've found it's incomplete.  There has been effort to support unsupported titles, but I don't know if it's been successful. http://www.logitech.com/en-us/articles/554

Comment: On the G15 it wasn't a standard key, but can you rig profile switching on your G13 to one of the G keys?  If so you might be able to devise a solution with autohotkey.

Answer (score -3):

I am not sure how your mouse seems to be aware of being in space or on the surface, but from what I know there isnt a way to change them to match, it would be something cryptic would need to implement.